# How do you differentiate between different characters within the same string after the occurance of a white space

Tags: java, string

I have modified my code, I am making a decoder that decodes as follows:

> "2" as "a", "22" as "b", "222" as "c", "3" as "d" etc

I've written the following logic to implement it

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the string encoded with appropriate T9 encoding algorithm");
    String lStr=input.nextLine();
    String[] tokens=lStr.split("\\s|0");
    System.out.printf("Number of elements are: %d\n The text entered is: ", tokens.length);
    for(String token: tokens)
    {
        if(token.equals("2")){
            output=token.replace("2", "a");
        }
        else if(token.equals("22")){
            output=token.replace("22","b");
        }

       //etc
```

If I give it an input like 2022 222 it decodes it as "abc" which is right but I wanted it to print "a bc" whenever it encounters a 0 as if in 2022 222, how can I achieve that, ive used 0 as a token along with white space, how can I tell it to put a space after reading 0 in the string?
Help please!

Comment: Could you post the remainder of the code?

Comment: My program now works fine, I have one problem though, assume my input is 20220222 then the output should be a b c, I mean there should be spaces between the characters if a 0 is encountered between the string, I am also using 0 as a token to separate the string, my question is how do I insert a space after a 0 is read by the compiler(i've used 0 as token as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String lStr=input.nextLine();` is the problem. Try checking the value of lStr at runtime - it will be the value of the whole *line* (perhaps unsurprisingly given the name of the method).

To continue with this approach, you'll need to read the whole line in as you do, but then check each *token* (there's a method to do this) for a match with your encoding scheme.

E.g. If you read a *line* in:

lStr = "2 22 222 2222";

which won't match your scheme at all - you don't have a value coded up as "2 22" do you?

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

You should split the line on spaces and for each of the elements you count the amount of 2's and substitute in the corresponding character. Then you don't get the switch creep either.

This is just an illustration:

```
String str = "2 22 222";
if (!str.matches("^[2\\s]+$")) {
  System.out.println("Invalid string!");
  return;
}
String res = "";
for (String elm : str.split("\\s+")) {
  int cnt = elm.length();
  res += (char) ('a' + cnt - 1) + " ";
}
System.out.println("res: "+ res);
```

`res` will be "a b c".

Answer (score 0):

Your encoding is broken:

- `AB` encodes as `222`
- `C` encodes as `222`

If you don't understand why this is a problem, more explanation will not help you.

If you want to have some fun writing your own encoder/decoder, consider the [playfair cypher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playfair_cipher).

Comment: He mentioned that all the 2's should be separated by a space. But if this wasn't the case then you're absolutely correct.

Comment: i use 0 for space, so a b is the input then the output of the encoder is 2022

Comment: "If you don't understand why this is a problem, more explanation will not help you."

Just the kind of helpful tone this site needs a lot less of.

Comment: the algorithm is such that if you give the cipher an input like ab the moment it encounters b after reading a it inserts a space after a, eg ab is the input the output is 2 22